# Key error "year" even though I have a column called year

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, linegraph

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

data = pd.read_csv("match_map_stats.csv")  

plt.figure()

Shanghai_Dragons_rule = data.loc[data["map_winner"] == "Shanghai Dragons"]


control_df = df.loc[(df["map_type"] == "control")]

#Year_df = data.loc[data["year"] == "2022"]

winrate = round(data["map_winner"].value_counts() / (data["map_winner"].value_counts() + data["map_loser"].value_counts()), 3) * 100

link = data["year"].unique()  


plt.plot(winrate,link)
plt.title(" Shanghai Dragons win rate over time")
plt.xticks(rotation=30, ha='right')
plt.xlabel("Year")
plt.ylabel("Wins")             

plt.show()
```

I'm trying to make a line graph on a teams control map win rate overtime, I tried using link = data["year"].unique()  to get the years on the x value but I keep getting an error

> # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise
>
> KeyError: 'year'   Even though I have year as one of my columns

[image: my database]

I tried putting # before my code to see if I can fix the issue but nothing worked and I tried examples online but none worked.

Comment: what's the output of `data.columns` ?

Comment: @PedroRocha sorry but what do you mean by what's the output of data.columns?

Comment: if you run `data.columns` in your jupyter notebook. What is the output that you get?

Comment: @PedroRocha how do I run data.columns?

Comment: You should insert `print(data.columns)` in your code. This will print the name of the columns of data. You should use the exact names or they will not be recognized. Maybe there is a space or something: "year ".